# htaccess redirect frontend routing to node.js backend

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, express

I have a node.js app that I moved to a bluehost VPS server and I can't get page requests to use the backend server.js file. In my root server folder I made a folder called myapp and put the backend server files there, and all the front-end is in public_html. I can connect to my server terminal via ssh and use npm start to run server.js, and it says its running on port 8080 just fine, but when I try to make a request to the front-end it doesn't redirect to the backend (myapp/server.js). Are my statics set up wrong, do I need to put something into htaccess to redirect front-end requests to my backend folder? Please help!